# how to use cutPoints in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

the code as follow

```py
symbols = array(SYMBOL, 0, 100)
symbols = symbols.distinct().sort!().append!("999999");
symRanges = symbols.cutPoints(100)
```

there's error message below

```sql
binNum is larger than the number of data points.
```

not sure how to use the cutPoints in DolphinDB

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear: the number of bins (100) is larger than the number of data points (1). `array(SYMBOL, 0, 100)` in dolphindb returns an empty vector instead of a vector with 100 elements.